# How to limit the height of a grid element to another grid element?

Tags: html, css

I've the following configuration:

```
<div id="grid">
 <div id="unlimited">/* Some data */</div>
 <div id="limited">/* Some other data */</div>
</div>
```

With the following css:

```
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
}

#limited {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

The #unlimited should have unlimited height (adjusted to it's content). But #limited should have a `max-height: heightOf(#unlimited)`. Is this possible without using any javascript?

If it's not possible using a grid, can this be done using a flex layout?

The height of the parent container of #grid is not determinated (the height of the parent should be adjusted to match the #unlimited height).

Comment: So basically `#limited` has same `max-height` as `#grid` height? Have you tried `max-height: 100%`?

Comment: @Justinas Yes, but this does not work, because the height of the parent container of the grid is not limited in height (the #unlimited can not expand if I do so).

Comment: @TemaniAfif Just explain to the questioner. He has edited with a reason for the reopen vote.

Comment: @m4n0 I have nothing to explain because the edit is irrelevant. If he *fully* read the duplicate he will get his answer because I am not defining any explicit height there and everything is defined by the content